# ajax php form validation- not calling php url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a php file and and ajax code form contact form validation like email and mobile number but when I click on sumbit button it is not going to php page form ajax. I need code that validates those fields and shows appropriate error message.

Below is my ajax code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_contact_form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
        var proceed = true;
        var form = this;

        //simple validation at client's end
        //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
        $(form).find(':required').each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            //check invalid email
            var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            }   

        }).keyup(function() { //reset previously set border colors on .keyup()
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        }).change(function() {  //for select box
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        }); 

        if(proceed){ //everything looks good! proceed...
            //get input field values data to be sent to server
            var post_url = $(this).attr("action"); //get form action url
            var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
            var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.ajax({
                url : post_url,
                type: request_method,
                dataType : 'json',
                data : form_data
            })
            .done(function(response){ 
                if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    $(form)[0].reset(); //reset this form upon success
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }
                $("#contact_results").html(output);
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please provide complete code samples. DOM and PHP would be helpful.
Also is the request executed (see Devtools > Network)? What is the response?
Is the JS submit listener executed? You can easily test it with `console.log`.
Also your `keyup` and `change` listener should not be attached on form submission. In this way they will be attached multiple times.

Comment: include your html form

Comment: Are you getting any console errors or are you able to see if there is any request going though on the console (xhr) tab?

Comment: i am getting 200 response code but not redirecting requested url